# How to avoid duplicate values in Helm charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When you deploy something using helm, you declare a variable on `values.yml` file and them use its value as `.Value.var_name`. For example, to declare my ingress domain name:

```
domain: mydomain.com
```

Then it is used as:

```
kind: Ingress
...
spec:
  rules:
    - host: .Values.domain
```

Now, imagine I add grafana chart as dependency.

```
dependencies:
  - name: grafana
    repository: https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
    version: 7.0.3
```

This chart requires `ingress.hosts` input, so I set this in `values.yml` as

```
domain: mydomain.com

grafana:
  ingress:
    hosts:
      - mydomain.com
```

However, I put `mydomain.com` twice and can be error prone. Is there any way to reference .Values inside `values.yml`? Maybe with templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May use [yaml anchor](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/) to achieve this function.

values.yaml

```yaml
domain: &domain mydomain.com

grafana:
  grafana:
    hosts:
      - *domain
```

templates/cm.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
data:
  domain: {{ $.Values.domain }}
  grafana: -| 
    {{- toYaml $.Values.grafana.grafana.hosts| nindent 4 }}
```

cmd

```bash
helm install test .
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  domain: mydomain.com
  grafana: -|
    - mydomain.com
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: test
  namespace: default
```